# Как получить чужой домен при запросе в AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
 if(event=="play"){
            $.ajax({ type: "post", url: "video.php", data: {id: '.$kp.', dt: document.referrer} 
           });
            yaCounter51365005.reachGoal("playerjs_play");
         }
      }
```

document.referrer с чужого домена у которого https - получаю пустое значение, это понятно, как можно по другому получить значение (домен) в ajax? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] не совсем то работает как надо, выдает только свой домен.

Я хочу получить данные с какого "домена" посетитель смотрит iframe.

У меня во всех файлах лежат

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: Так и не понял, чей именно домен вы хотите получить?

Comment: @andreymal чужой же, невозможно?

Comment: Какой чужой-то? С которого перешли на ваш сайт? В общем случае это невозможно, если этот чужой сайт сам не разрешит вам получить себя https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Comment: @andreymal возможно я неправильно сформулировал вопрос, допустим у меня клиент разместил iframe плеер с нашего источника к себе (его сайт в SSL), после запуска плеера данные лишь получаю только IP, а домен его сайта пуст в переменной, именно это и есть дело в SSL, по другому получить никак?

Comment: Вы что-то странное рассказываете, вроде бы разместить http-ифрейм на https-сайте невозможно. Если же ифрейм тоже https, то особых проблем быть вроде бы и не должно

Comment: @andreymal Как ни странно, наш сайт как и iframe все равно имеет SSL

Comment: Значит сайт, судя по всему, запрещает реферреры

Comment: @andreymal ну и ладно, спасибо за подсказку